# Query showing wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My below query gets records from table `penilaian_header` & `penilaian_detail`

```
select *    
from 
( 
    select 
        row, a.tanggal,b.OutletCode,c.Nilai,a.Nip,b.Fullname,a.KodePenilaian,
        f.Description as posisilama, d.ShortDesc as posisibaru 
    from penilaian_header a 
        left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip 
        left join Position f on b.PositionCode = f.PositionCode 
        left join Position d on a.PositionCode = d.PositionCode 
        left join Penilaian_Detail e on a.KodePenilaian = e.KodePenilaianH 
        left join arealeader g on g.OutletCode = b.OutletCode 
        left join (
                    select 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KodePenilaianH ORDER BY idPenilaiand DESC) AS Row, 
                        Nilai,
                        KodePenilaianH 
                    from penilaian_Detail
                    ) c on a.KodePenilaian = e.KodePenilaianH 
    where a.Outlet like '%%' and Periode like '%%'  
) nilai 
pivot 
( 
    sum(nilai) for row in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) 
) piv;
```

My record in `penilaian_header` 
[image]

My record in `penilaian_detail`

[image]

When I run my query, I get this result. 
[image]

The result should be same as `penilaian_detail`. Please tell me how to fix it.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7e4d/8

Thanks to @dhruvjoshi for explanation. Now the results are like what i'm expected

first, I delete this 
 `left join Penilaian_Detail e on a.KodePenilaian = e.KodePenilaianH`

then i change this
`on a.KodePenilaian = e.KodePenilaianH` to `on a.KodePenilaian = c.KodePenilaianH`

Comment: i never use sqlfiddle . But i try it, here is my link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ec6e/1

Comment: You'd also need to insert some data in tables to evaluate the query

Comment: i've insert some http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7e4d/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that because of `JOINs` you had repeated rows in result set for inner query.
**[See inner query fiddle evaluation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7e4d/10)**

Corrected query is below

```
select *    
from 
(
     select 
      distinct ---added distinct here to avoid repetition
      row, a.tanggal,b.OutletCode,c.Nilai,a.Nip,b.Fullname,a.KodePenilaian,f.Description as posisilama,d.ShortDesc as posisibaru
     from penilaian_header a 
        left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip
        left join Position f on b.PositionCode = f.PositionCode
        left join Position d on a.PositionCode = d.PositionCode 
        left join Penilaian_Detail e on a.KodePenilaian = e.KodePenilaianH
        left join arealeader g on g.OutletCode = b.OutletCode
        left join (
                    select 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KodePenilaianH ORDER BY idPenilaiand DESC) AS Row, 
                        Nilai,KodePenilaianH 
                    from penilaian_Detail
                    ) c on a.KodePenilaian = e.KodePenilaianH 
) nilai 
pivot
(
  sum(nilai)
  for row in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) piv;
```

**[SQL demo link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7e4d/9)**

Comment: well, it's work know. thanks to you. I only need to add distinct?

Comment: @Boby Once again you tried the query without distinct. Corrected query link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4111/5

Comment: I didnt input 15,16, . I only input 1 - 10

Comment: See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4111/6. This is the inner query with distinct; You get 15 because 7+8 is=15 and you get two rows in JOIN one with c.Nilai=7 and other with c.Nilai=8 because there are two rows in your source table, although they are for different KodeTrKriteria